# Custom home button icon looking bigger than usual

Tags: android, layout

Hi I have an activity with back button enabled at the left side of the activity. Actually my activity is AppCompatActivity so I used toolbar at the top of the activity layout file. Then I changed home indicator icon programmatically. But it is not looking very well. I also used different variant for different density. But I don't know why?

Here is my code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/ll_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ScrollView
        //////
        />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my activity onCreate

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.profileedit);
        mTopToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mTopToolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.icon_back_to_home));

        setTitle("");
    }
```

here is my problem

[image]

The home button icon I have set is looking bigger. I also checked the different drawable size folder that also not the issue.

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` this is sufficient, this will add icon automatically

Comment: this is not showing back icon at the left of the activity. any way thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cereate back button image with different size of icon.

Go to res -> new -> Image Asset.

Select Icon Type -> Actionbar and Tab Icons.

Asset Type -> Image and select your icon from system.

Comment: Nice, instead of Actionbar and Tab Icons, I have created launcher icons. silly mistake